# Can't pass props.style to "@emotion/styled" component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I'm using emotion styled components. I have a component called `Layered` which I define as follows:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

interface LayeredProps {
    [key: string]: any
}

const Layered = (props: LayeredProps) => {

    return (
      <ComponentWrapper style={props.style}>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>World</p>
      </ComponentWrapper>
    )

};

export default Layered;

const ComponentWrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`
```

In my main code, I create another component called `<LayeredModified />` which is supposed to be `Layered` with some extra styling. The styling is:

```
const LayeredModified = styled(Layered)`
  margin-left: 20px !important;
  margin-right: 20px !important;
`
```

`Layered` itself is never explicitly rendered, only `LayeredModified`. However, when it renders, it does so without any `margin` adjustments. In other words, only the props defined within the `Layered` component are shown, and not those defined in `LayeredModified`. I tried printing `props.style` in `Layered` and it's always `undefined`.

I know I'm not passing an explicit `style` parameter, but I thought the point of Emotion Styles was that it passed whatever styles you defined for that component automatically. If explicit passing is needed, I'm not sure how to do so without completely redefining the style inline, which defeats the purpose of the `const LayeredModified` component.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing applying the passed styles to the component. You need to add a className prop to ComponentWrapper and then use the props.className in it to apply the passed styles.

```
interface LayeredProps {
  className?: string,
  [key: string]: any
}

const Layered = (props : LayeredProps) => {
  return (
    <ComponentWrapper className={`${props.className}`}>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>World</p>
    </ComponentWrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, the only difference I see between your code and mine is that you've restyled one line like this: `const Layered: React.FC<LayeredProps> = (props) =`. Is that what you mean by "You need to add a className prop to ComponentWrapper and then use the props.className in it to apply the passed styles?" (I don't see any other change in your example.) If I make that change, though, it has the same issue as before --- style isn't applied and shows as undefined. (Incidentally, I do have `className="cw"` in my `ComponentWrapper`, I just left that out of my example. Is it important?)

Comment: I think what your answer is saying (and what it is missing) is that I need to put ```className={`${props.className}`}``` in `ComponentWrapper`. That does indeed work. If you can add that line into your answer (or even remove the excess code except for ComponentWrapper for clarity, and put it in that), then I can accept the answer.

Comment: It doesn't actually need the props passed to the ComponentWrapper style definition, only the className to the actual object implementation itself.